# Launching WorkerService(.exe) from WPF Project's Output Folder Issue

Tags: c#, wpf, worker-service

Launching a dependent WorkerService .exe from a WPF project folder throws an error in WorkerService.exe:

```
Unhandled exception. System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'. The system cannot find the file specified.
File name: 'System.Diagnostics.EventLog, Version=8.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=cc7b13ffcd2ddd51'
   at Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog.EventLogLogger..ctor(String name, EventLogSettings settings, IExternalScopeProvider externalScopeProvider)
...and so on
```

The projects are default and empty, and there's nothing to look at.

[image: solution structure]

WPF output folder:

[image: WPF proj output]

[image: console output]

---

**However, launching the same exe from the regular console application(ConsoleServiceStarter) project folder happens without any issues.**

---

Installing Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting in a WPF project doesn't change anything. **Manually** copying the output files from SimpleWorkerService to WpfServiceStarter certainly solves the problem.

What needs to be configured to fix this?

Comment: difficult to help you without more details.   Showing the source code could help...

Comment: @Frenchy all three projects were created from scratch without any modifications made to them

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.